# Standardize Display Date time in SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, datetime-format

When I query in SQL Server I find `datetime` is displayed in different formats in the below columns

```
a.BATCHREG_TM1, a.BATCHREG_TM2, a.BATCHREG_TM3, a.BATCHREG_TM4, a.BATCHREG_TM5,
a.BATCHREG_TM6, a.BATCHREG_TM7, a.BATCHREG_TM8, a.BATCHREG_TM9, a.BATCHREG_TM10,
a.REG_TM, a.REWORK_TM,
```

Requirements:

1. Display in DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS one format
2. Display values of column's fuel and engine,etc in alternate name

Example : If 'U' in Fuel , display as Diesel, if 'G' As Gasoline.

```
SELECT 
    a.DEVICE_ID, a.MES_SEQ, a.BODY_NO, a.STN_NM,
    c.LINE_CD, a.[SHIFT], a.REG_TM, a.REWORK_TM, a.FIRST_STATUS,
    CAST(TOR_VALUE1 AS float) / 100 AS TOR_VALUE1,
    CAST(TOR_VALUE2 AS float) / 100 AS TOR_VALUE2,
    CAST(TOR_VALUE3 AS float) / 100 AS TOR_VALUE3,
    CAST(TOR_VALUE4 AS float) / 100 AS TOR_VALUE4,
    CAST(TOR_VALUE5 AS float) / 100 AS TOR_VALUE5,
    CAST(TOR_VALUE6 AS float) / 100 AS TOR_VALUE6,
    CAST(TOR_VALUE7 AS float) / 100 AS TOR_VALUE7,
    CAST(TOR_VALUE8 AS float) / 100 AS TOR_VALUE8,
    CAST(TOR_VALUE9 AS float) / 100 AS TOR_VALUE9,
    CAST(TOR_VALUE10 AS float) / 100 AS TOR_VALUE10,
    CONVERT(INT, ANG_VALUE1) AS ANG_VALUE1,
    CONVERT(INT, ANG_VALUE2) AS ANG_VALUE2,
    CONVERT(INT, ANG_VALUE3) AS ANG_VALUE3,
    CONVERT(INT, ANG_VALUE4) AS ANG_VALUE4,
    CONVERT(INT, ANG_VALUE5) AS ANG_VALUE5,
    CONVERT(INT, ANG_VALUE6) AS ANG_VALUE6,
    CONVERT(INT, ANG_VALUE7) AS ANG_VALUE7,
    CONVERT(INT, ANG_VALUE8) AS ANG_VALUE8,
    CONVERT(INT, ANG_VALUE9) AS ANG_VALUE9,
    CONVERT(INT, ANG_VALUE10) AS ANG_VALUE10,
    a.BATCHREG_TM1,a.BATCHREG_TM2,a.BATCHREG_TM3,a.BATCHREG_TM4,a.BATCHREG_TM5,
    a.BATCHREG_TM6,a.BATCHREG_TM7,a.BATCHREG_TM8,a.BATCHREG_TM9,a.BATCHREG_TM10,
    a.BATCH_STATUS,a.TOTAL_STATUS,
    a.REWORK_STATUS,a.REWORK_JOBFLAG,a.PLANT,a.SCAN_CHK,a.TOT_BATCH_NUM,
    a.VIEWFLAG,a.TOOLSNETCHK,a.JOB_NUM,a.REWORKJOB_NUM,c.LH_RH,
    c.DEVICE_STATUS, c.USE_219_CHK
    [MODEL], [DRIVE],[BODY],[TRANSMISSION],[FUEL],[ENGINE],[BRAKESYSTEM],[AIRCON],[REGION]
FROM 
    [C].[dbo].[NUT] a
LEFT JOIN 
    [C].[dbo].[IF_ORDER] b ON a.body_no = b.body_no
LEFT JOIN 
    [C.[dbo].[REG] c ON a.device_id = c.device_id
OUTER APPLY 
    (VALUES (
       SUBSTRING(b.[spec219], 2, 1),
       SUBSTRING(b.[spec219], 3, 1),
       SUBSTRING(b.[spec219], 4, 1),
       SUBSTRING(b.[spec219], 7, 1),
       SUBSTRING(b.[spec219], 8, 1),
       SUBSTRING(b.[spec219], 9, 1),
       SUBSTRING(b.[spec219], 13, 1),
       SUBSTRING(b.[spec219], 28, 1),
    SUBSTRING(b.[spec219], 218, 1)
)) v ([MODEL], [DRIVE],[BODY],[TRANSMISSION],[FUEL],[ENGINE],[BRAKESYSTEM],[AIRCON],[REGION])
WHERE 
    a.reg_tm >= '20200320000000' AND a.reg_tm <= '20200320015959'
ORDER BY 
    a.reg_tm
```

I tried with this code:

```
case 
   when isnumeric(left(a.BATCHREG_TM1,4)) = 1 then cast(a.BATCHREG_TM1 as date) 
   when len(a.BATCHREG_TM1) = 10 then convert(date, a.BATCHREG_TM1, 103) 
   when len(a.BATCHREG_TM1) = 8 then convert(date, a.BATCHREG_TM1, 3) 
   when charindex('/',a.BATCHREG_TM1) = 0 and isnumeric(a.BATCHREG_TM1) = 0 then convert(date, a.BATCHREG_TM1, 106) 
end as [date]
```

```
.----------------.-----------.---------------------.---------------------.--------------.--------------.--------------.------.--------.
|     REG_TM     | REWORK_TM |    BATCHREG_TM1     |    BATCHREG_TM2     | BATCHREG_TM3 | BATCHREG_TM4 | BATCHREG_TM5 | FUEL | ENGINE |
:----------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------+--------:
| 20200320000001 | NULL      | 2020-03-20:00:00:01 | NULL                | NULL         | NULL         | NULL         | U    | J      |
:----------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------+--------:
| 20200320000001 | NULL      | 20200319235441      | 20200319235443      | NULL         | NULL         | NULL         | U    | J      |
:----------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------+--------:
| 20200320000002 | NULL      | 2020-03-20:00:00:03 | NULL                | NULL         | NULL         | NULL         | G    | Z      |
:----------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------+--------:
| 20200320000002 | NULL      | 2020-03-19:23:59:57 | 2020-03-20:00:00:01 | NULL         | NULL         | NULL         | U    | J      |
:----------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+------+--------:
| 20200320000003 | NULL      | 2020-03-20:00:00:00 | 2020-03-20:00:00:02 | NULL         | NULL         | NULL         | U    | J      |
'----------------'-----------'---------------------'---------------------'--------------'--------------'--------------'------'--------'
```

Comment: Date and time data types don't have a format. The fact that some rows show a value like `20200319235441` and others `2020-03-20:00:00:03` means that the column is **not** a date and time data type but a `(n)varchar`. That is the problem here, your data type is wrong. Unfortunately your only choice here is to spend time fixing the data to an ISO format (I recommend `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn`) and then changing your column's definition to a date and time data type (using `ALTER TABLE`).

Comment: Side note: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: Thanks! yes the columns is char(14) format. I don't want to disturb modifying the Table. i just need to query and export the data. @Lamu

Answer (score 2):

Like I mention, you need to fix your design here; that this the **only** solution.

In the example you give there are 2 formats, `yyyyMMddhhmmss` and `yyyy-MM-dd:hh:mm:ss`, so I am going to provide solutions for these 2 formats. If you have more, then you will have to address these as well.

First, we need to update the values to an `ISO` format. I'm going to use `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss`.

```
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET YourDate = STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(V.YourDate,13,0,':'),11,0,':'),9,0,'T'),7,0,'-'),5,0,'-')
WHERE YourDate LIKE '[0-2][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9][0-2][0-9][0-5][0-9][0-5][0-9]';


UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET YourDate = STUFF(V.YourDate,11,1,'T')
WHERE YourDate LIKE '[0-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]:[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]';
```

Now those two different formats are in the ISO format. I suggest you also then check for any other values that aren't valid with the following query:

```
SELECT YourDate
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(date,YourDate,126) IS NULL
  AND YourDate IS NOT NULL;
```

After the above query doesn't return any rows (beacuse you've fixed all the bad values) you can fix the column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ALTER COLUMN YourDate datetime2(0);
```

Now your column is actually a Date and Time column, and it will provide a date and time value.